# How to limit user input to a elements of List

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating my tic tac toe game 
I want to limit the input of user to elements of list.

my code goes as follows

```
from random import randint

def player_input():

    turn_r = randint(0,1)

    if(turn_r == 0):        
        def player1():
            p1marker=0
            while not int(p1marker) in range(0,9):
                p1marker = raw_input("Where Should I Place Your X : ")
            board[p1marker-1] = 'X'
    if(turn_r == 1):
        def player2():
            p2marker=0
            while not int(p2marker) in range(0,9):
                p2marker = raw_input("Where Should I Place Your X : ")
            board[p2marker-1] = 'X'
```

well instead of `range(0,9)` i want the while loop to check elements of list and also avoid X or 0 once added by user in the list

Comment: since i am beginner please explain the code too and please do not use error, except or any other new concepts

Comment: Just what do you mean by "do not use error"? What "new concepts" do you not want us to use--or to explain it differently, which concepts do you want us to use?

Comment: In Python 2.x `range(0, 9)` actually produces a list: `[0, 1, 2 ... 8]`, so just replace your `range()` call with a reference to your list.

Comment: @zwer but still if the user enters X or 0 which will be in the list after first entry. Than X or 0 will be accepted but X or 0 are not a valid input in tic tac toe

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sir Do Not Use Errors and Exception Handling and please help me solve this problem i.e. Once User Enters a number that is 5 x will be marked (if its player2 turn o will be marked) if than user enters x or o it will get accepted so how to avoid if a user enters x or o. Since x or o will already be in the list it will get accepted but x and o are not valid inputs since they are not positions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code, in its current state is pretty useless actually. Observe:

```
from random import randint

def player_input():
    turn_r = randint(0,1)
    if(turn_r == 0):        
        def player1():
            ...

    if(turn_r == 1):
        def player2():
            ...
```

Depending on the value of `turn_r`, you either define this function, or you define that.

Example:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> if i:
...   def f1(): pass
... elif i == 0:
...   def f2(): pass
... 
>>> f1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'f1' is not defined
>>> f2
<function f2 at 0x104a511b8>
```

The other thing is, if `turn_r == 0`, is true, the second condition can never happen. You are better off converting that second `if` to an `elif`. It makes for better code.

Finally, all you need to do is replace `range(0, 9)` with some list of yours, if that's what you want.

However, it will serve no purpose unless you call either of those functions.

Comment: @zwer but still if the user enters X or 0 which will be in the list after first entry. Than X or 0 will be accepted but X or 0 are not a valid input in tic tac toe

Comment: @mvrht Nope, it won't, because you're not adding X to the list.

Comment: i am adding x to the list it is tic tac toe once user enters 5 as his position in the list the entry with 5 will be replace with X or 0. so i also want the while to do not accept X or 0

Comment: @mvrht Don't you think it would be smarter to keep a list of visited indices? If the user enters an index, store that index. Also have a counter or a flag to increment, so that you know if the user entered X or 0. This is outside the scope of this question, so if you have any more queries I recommend marking an answer and closing this question, and opening a new question. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace `range(0,9)` with your list. It should work exactly the same!

However, there are other problems with your code:

```
p1marker=0
while not int(p1marker) in range(0,9):
    p1marker = raw_input("Where Should I Place Your X : ")
```

This loop will never execute, since you have already declared `p1marker` as `0`.

Also, if you want to use `board[p1marker-1] = 'X'`, make sure `p1marker` is a number. As it is, you'll get an error for trying to subtract an integer from a string.

Comment: but still if the user enters X or 0 which will be in the list after first entry. Than X or 0 will be accepted but X or 0 are not a valid input in tic tac toe

Answer (score 0):

take a list of your choice. 
Suppose:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Then replace the range(0,9) with x

```
while not int(p1marker) in x:
```

Comment: but still if the user enters X or 0 which will be in the list after first entry. Than X or 0 will be accepted but X or 0 are not a valid input in tic tac toe